# pandas multiple array calculation with different shape and missing data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
     a   b   c                    c   d   e
0  nan   2   4               0  nan   6   8
1   30  60  90      (-)      1  100 110 120 
2   20 nan nan
```

Hello, I'm trying to subtract two arrays above and expecting the result like below.

```
    a    b    c    d    e
0   0    2    4   -6   -8
1  30   60  -10 -110 -120 
2  20    0
```

Is this kind of calculation possible in pandas? 
If it is, please let me know.

I already checked [Working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) docs, but unfortunately it wasn't so helpful to me at this time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found expected solution

```
dfA.sub(dfB, fill_value=0).fillna(0)
```

last part of code above

```
.fillna(0)
```

is because of

**fill_value:** *Fill missing (NaN) values with this value. If both DataFrame locations are missing, the result will be missing - [pandas.DataFrame.sub](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)*